# Remove extra dots in float value before a separater " , " occurs using java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am generating a statistical calculator application.

So I want to format input from edittext like this
i/p = 3.5.6, 6.5  to  3.5 , 6.5

Using " , " (comma) as separator so splitting the input string to float array when a " , " occurs.

I want to ignore 3.5[.6] and generate array like this
s[1] = 3.5 , s[2] = 6.5

While calculating mean application crashes due to extra " . " dots.

```
s = it.getText().toString(); //"it" is edittext
s=s.replaceAll( ",+" , "," );
String[] strarray =s.split(",");

float[] farray = new float[strarray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < strarray.length; i++) 
{
    farray[i] = Float.parseFloat(strarray[i]);
}
```

--DEBUG LOGCAT--

```
W/dalvikvm(3051): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40a71930)
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "6.7."
    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:310)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
    at com.cal.mc2.Mean$1.onClick(Mean.java:67)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)`
   `at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Force finishing activity com.cal.mc2/.Mean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this simple function (IdeOne link here: https://ideone.com/utKPjP):

```
public static float myParseFloat(String str) {
    int firstDot = str.indexOf('.');
    if (firstDot != -1) {
        int secondDot = str.indexOf('.', firstDot+1);
        return Float.parseFloat(secondDot == -1 ? str : str.substring(0,secondDot));
    }
    return Float.parseFloat(str);
}
```

Then you just replace this statement in your code:

```
farray[i] = Float.parseFloat(strarray[i]);
```

with:

```
farray[i] = myParseFloat(strarray[i]);
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake ..now callled myParseFloat after s.split(","); IT WORKED THANKS A LOT..

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "3.5.6, 6.5";
    s = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d\\.\\d)\\.\\d", "");// positive look behind. Only replace `.[digit]` if it is preceeded by [digit][.][digit]
    System.out.println(s);
    String[] arr = s.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

}
```

O/P :

```
3.5, 6.5   --> value of s after replacement
[3.5,  6.5]  --> array contents
```

Comment: It worked but if I give only one input as " 3.5. "  then application force closes.

Comment: I tried with your input.. My code woks fine.. What is the error?